# Cloud Windows Server 19 Routing

Tags: windows, networking, routing

So I'm not sure if "routing" is the right word to use but essentially that's what I want to do. Basically I have a Windows Server 2019 VPS that I have tunneled to my router at home (comcast business) and essentially I want to use this cloud server as a relay/firewall that will allow incoming port traffic to be sent through the tunnel and handled accordingly.

I can either handle NAT on the server or on my router at home, I'm guessing at home would be easiest. I've never tried to use windows server as a routing system so this is completely new to me.

I have 1 NIC with 2 public IP's assigned to it. I have one IP as my management IP and the other as the public facing one I will be sending and processing traffic through.

Routes have been added to the subnets behind my on prem router and that's talking as it should, however I can't get the port based traffic to pass through from the second WAN IP to the inside server through my tunnel.

I have Remote Access and Routing but I'm not sure if I need to use that and configure NAT for the 1 interface I have OR I just need to use the firewall and netsh commands.

Currently I have a firewall policy allowing 28015 via 70.39.93.xxx public address and the following netsh config

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=28015 listenaddress=70.39.93.xxx connectport=28015 connectaddress=10.10.21.9
```

I tried to change portproxy to the "Ethernet" interface since that's the only interface I have but it does not allow me to do that.

Sorry if this is a broad question but I've read a few articles to try and figure out how to do this and none work and I still don't quite understand.

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand this question. How is your (local) routing working with multiple nic's? How is this "tunneled to my router at home" working and wqhat does your router do with those packets?